# How to ping with MySQL X Dev API

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-x-devapi

In old MySQL API you can use `mysql_ping()` to archive that. But is there any similar function in X Dev API?

Comment: it still works https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-ping.html

Comment: @nbk Actually I mean X DevAPI.